# How get SystemUI components replaced by CarSystemUI components in Android 12

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, android-automotive

Android 12 provides for example a specific implementation for the "Toast" for the car device. The source code of this can be found here: [CarToastUI](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Car/SystemUI/+/refs/heads/android12-release/src/com/android/systemui/car/toast/CarToastUI.java). This class extends `ToastUI`, which can be found here: [ToastUI](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android12-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/toast/ToastUI.java).

When a "car device" is built from the AOSP, the `CarToastUI` class is used instead of the `ToastUI` class.

**How does this replacement mechanism work?**

What I found out so far:

- the System UI uses Dagger 2 for dependency injection
- there is some documentation for this here: [dagger.md](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/docs/dagger.md)
- there exists a [CarGlobalRootComponent](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Car/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/CarGlobalRootComponent.java;bpv=0;bpt=1), which extends `GlobalRootComponent` and overrides methods
- similarly the [CarSystemUIFactory](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Car/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/CarSystemUIFactory.java;bpv=0;bpt=1) overrides methods of `SystemUIFactory`
- there is a [configuration](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Car/SystemUI/res/values/config.xml;l=125;bpv=0;bpt=0) where system UI components are excluded and car system ui components are included
- from the CarSystemUI blueprint file I can see, that SystemUI gets overwritten: [Android.bp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Car/SystemUI/+/refs/heads/android12-release/Android.bp#146)